# DES Implementation in Java: Error during Key Generation Phase

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, des

I am a student doing a mini-project - DES implementation.
I had a doubt previously about converting a 64 bit key to 56 bit key, and could do that successfully, thanks to some guidance received here.

I have divided my implementation into the key-gen phase (where I generate a new key for each of the 16 rounds) and the encryption phase.

However, I am not able to generate the correct keys.
I did an example manually using "abcdefgh" as key and I am not able to reproduce the results in my program.

The DES keygen phase involves:

1. Dividing 56-bit key into 2 28 bit keys. I store 28 bits in 4 bytes as `leftkey28[4]` (which has the last 4 bits as 0) & `rightkey28[4]` (which has the first 4 bits as 0)
2. These 28 bit groups are left circular shifted using (<< 1 & << 2 in the original algorithm and then combined to get a new 56-bit key). However, because of this problem, I scrapped left shifting by 2 for now, and am only left circular shifting by 1. And still, the root of this problem is untraceable.

The problem seems to be in the line `Round#2 Byte#2` in my output.

I will be grateful for any guidance or hints towards finding out the root cause.
(
P.S. I have never done so much bit manipulation before!
The code is not optimized or written according to Java rules/conventions as I just wanted to make it work before doing any other things
)

Thanks in advance.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * @author krish 2nd Aug, 2011
 */

    class DES {

final static int KEY_LENGTH = 8; // 8 byte key, 64 bits
final static int BLOCK_SIZE = 8; // 8 byte blocks, 64 bits
final static int NUM_ROUNDS = 16; // 16 rounds per block

// =======================================================================
// FOR KEY TRANSFORMATION
int[] compressionPermutation = { 14, 17, 11, 24, 1, 5, 3, 28, 15, 6, 21,
        10, 23, 19, 12, 4, 26, 8, 16, 7, 27, 20, 13, 2, 41, 52, 31, 37, 47,
        55, 30, 40, 51, 45, 33, 48, 44, 49, 39, 56, 34, 53, 46, 42, 50, 36,
        29, 32 };

// int[] keyShiftValue = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };
// ---
// don't need this
// =======================================================================

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter an 8 char key: ");
    String inputKey, inputMsg;
    char[] inputArray;
    byte[] key64 = new byte[8];
    byte[] key56 = new byte[7];
    int counter;

    try {
        // get key, key length() >= 8 chars

        // inputKey = br.readLine();// uncomment later!!$$$$$$$
        inputKey = "abcdefgh";
        System.out.println(inputKey);
        if (inputKey.length() < 8) {
            System.out.println("Key < 8 B. Exiting. . .");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        // java char has 16 bits instead of 8 bits as in C,
        // so convert it to 8 bit char by getting lower order byte &
        // discarding higher order byte; &
        // consider only first 8 chars even if input > 8
        inputArray = inputKey.toCharArray();
        for (counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
            key64[counter] = (byte) inputArray[counter];

        // converting 64bit key to 56 bit key
        for (counter = 0; counter < KEY_LENGTH - 1; counter++) {
            key64[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] >>> 1);
            key64[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] << 1);
        }
        for (counter = 0; counter < KEY_LENGTH - 1; counter++) {
            key56[counter] = (byte) (key64[counter] << counter);
            key56[counter] = (byte) (key56[counter] | (key64[counter + 1] >>> (KEY_LENGTH - 1 - counter)));
        }
        /*
         * Conversion from 64 to 56 bit testing code
         * 
         * System.out.println("64 to 56 test:"); System.out.println(new
         * String(key56)); System.out.println(); for (int counter1 = 0;
         * counter1 < 7; counter1++) { for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0;
         * counter2--) { System.out.println(key56[counter1] & (1 <<
         * counter2)); } System.out.println(); }
         */

        // end of obtaining 56bit key

        // KEY GENERATION PHASE
        // DS USED - compressionPermutation

        byte[] leftKey28 = new byte[4];
        byte[] rightKey28 = new byte[4];
        byte circularBit;
        byte[][] newKey56 = new byte[16][7];

        // new 56 bit key for the first round, then loop for other rounds
        leftKey28[0] = key56[0];
        leftKey28[1] = key56[1];
        leftKey28[2] = key56[2];
        leftKey28[3] = (byte) (key56[3] & 11110000);

        // rightKey28[0] = (byte) (key56[3] & 00001111);
        // prob here, doesnt work as given above??
        rightKey28[0] = (byte) (key56[3] - leftKey28[3]);
        rightKey28[1] = key56[4];
        rightKey28[2] = key56[5];
        rightKey28[3] = key56[6];

        /*
         * // printing starts here System.out.print("1 Byte # 0" + "     ");
         * for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0; counter2--) {
         * System.out.print(leftKey28[0] & (1 << counter2));
         * System.out.print(", "); } System.out.println(); // printing ends
         * here
         */

        circularBit = (byte) (leftKey28[0] & (1 << 7));

        leftKey28[0] = (byte) (leftKey28[0] << 1);
        leftKey28[0] = (byte) (leftKey28[0] | ((((int) leftKey28[1]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        leftKey28[1] = (byte) (leftKey28[1] << 1);
        leftKey28[1] = (byte) (leftKey28[1] | ((((int) leftKey28[2]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        leftKey28[2] = (byte) (leftKey28[2] << 1);
        leftKey28[2] = (byte) (leftKey28[2] | ((((int) leftKey28[3]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        leftKey28[3] = (byte) (leftKey28[3] << 1);
        leftKey28[3] = (byte) (leftKey28[3] | ((((int) circularBit) & 0xff) >>> 3));

        circularBit = (byte) (rightKey28[0] & (1 << 3));
        circularBit <<= 4;

        rightKey28[0] = (byte) (rightKey28[0] << 1);
        rightKey28[0] = (byte) (rightKey28[0] | ((((int) rightKey28[1]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        rightKey28[1] = (byte) (rightKey28[1] << 1);
        rightKey28[1] = (byte) (rightKey28[1] | ((((int) rightKey28[2]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        rightKey28[2] = (byte) (rightKey28[2] << 1);
        rightKey28[2] = (byte) (rightKey28[2] | ((((int) rightKey28[3]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

        rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] << 1);
        rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] | ((((int) circularBit) & 0xff) >>> 3));

        newKey56[0][0] = leftKey28[0];
        newKey56[0][1] = leftKey28[1];
        newKey56[0][2] = leftKey28[2];
        newKey56[0][3] = (byte) (leftKey28[3] | rightKey28[0]);
        newKey56[0][4] = rightKey28[1];
        newKey56[0][5] = rightKey28[2];
        newKey56[0][6] = rightKey28[3];
        // we have a new left circular shifted key in newKey56

        // done testing for newkey56[0] // left and right testing code
        for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 7; counter1++) {
            System.out.print("Round#0 Byte#" + counter1 + "  ");
            for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0; counter2--) {
                if (counter2 == 3)
                    System.out.print("   ");
                if ((newKey56[0][counter1] & (1 << counter2)) > 0) {
                    System.out.print("1");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("0");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        // left and right testing code ends here

        // for round 1 to 15: left circular shift each 28 bit block by 1{
        for (int round = 1; round < NUM_ROUNDS; round++) {
            // for the first round, then loop for other rounds
            leftKey28[0] = newKey56[round - 1][0];
            leftKey28[1] = newKey56[round - 1][1];
            leftKey28[2] = newKey56[round - 1][2];
            leftKey28[3] = (byte) (newKey56[round - 1][3] & 11110000);

            // rightKey28[0] = (byte) (newKey56[round - 1][3] & 00001111);
            rightKey28[0] = (byte) (newKey56[round - 1][3] - leftKey28[3]);
            rightKey28[1] = newKey56[round - 1][4];
            rightKey28[2] = newKey56[round - 1][5];
            rightKey28[3] = newKey56[round - 1][6];

            // if (round == 1 || round == 8 || round == 15) {
            // left circular shift by 1
            circularBit = (byte) (leftKey28[0] & (1 << 7));

            leftKey28[0] <<= 1;
            leftKey28[0] |= ((((int) leftKey28[1]) & 0xff) >>> 7);

            leftKey28[1] <<= 1;
            leftKey28[1] |= ((((int) leftKey28[2]) & 0xff) >>> 7);

            // ////////////////////////error here ////////////////////////////
            leftKey28[2] <<= 1;
            leftKey28[2] |= ((((int) leftKey28[3]) & 0xff) >>> 7);
            // ////////////////////////error here //////////////////////////

            leftKey28[3] <<= 1;
            leftKey28[3] |= ((((int) circularBit) & 0xff) >>> 3);

            circularBit = (byte) (rightKey28[0] & (1 << 3));
            circularBit <<= 4;

            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////
            rightKey28[0] = (byte) (rightKey28[0] << 1);
            rightKey28[0] &= 00001111;
            rightKey28[0] = (byte) (rightKey28[0] | ((((int) rightKey28[1]) & 0xff) >>> 7));
            // //////////////////////////////////////////////////

            rightKey28[1] = (byte) (rightKey28[1] << 1);
            rightKey28[1] = (byte) (rightKey28[1] | ((((int) rightKey28[2]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

            rightKey28[2] = (byte) (rightKey28[2] << 1);
            rightKey28[2] = (byte) (rightKey28[2] | ((((int) rightKey28[3]) & 0xff) >>> 7));

            rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] << 1);
            rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] | ((((int) circularBit) & 0xff) >>> 7));
            // } else {
            // // left circular shift by 2
            // }

            newKey56[round][0] = leftKey28[0];
            newKey56[round][1] = leftKey28[1];
            newKey56[round][2] = leftKey28[2];
            newKey56[round][3] = (byte) (leftKey28[3] | rightKey28[0]);
            newKey56[round][4] = rightKey28[1];
            newKey56[round][5] = rightKey28[2];
            newKey56[round][6] = rightKey28[3];

            // testing code for all keys for rounds 1 to 15
            System.out.println();
            for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 7; counter1++) {
                System.out.print("Round#" + round + "  Byte#" + counter1
                        + "  ");
                for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0; counter2--) {
                    if (counter2 == 3)
                        System.out.print("   ");
                    if ((newKey56[round][counter1] & (1 << counter2)) > 0) {
                        System.out.print("1");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("0");
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (round == 2)
                break;
            // testing code ends

        }// for loop ends

        /*
         * // newKey56 testing code
         * System.out.println("new56key testing here"); for (counter = 0;
         * counter < NUM_ROUNDS; counter++) { System.out.println(new
         * String(newKey56[counter])); System.out.println();
         * 
         * for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < 7; counter1++) {
         * System.out.print("Round # " + counter + " Byte # " + counter1 +
         * "     "); for (int counter2 = 7; counter2 >= 0; counter2--) {
         * System.out.print(newKey56[counter][counter1] & (1 << counter2));
         * System.out.print(", "); } System.out.println(); } }
         */

        // DO KEY COMPRESSION ROUTINE HERE

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
    }

    Enter an 8 char key: 
    abcdefgh
    Round#0 Byte#0  1100   0001
    Round#0 Byte#1  1000   1011
    Round#0 Byte#2  0001   0110
    Round#0 Byte#3  0100   1100
    Round#0 Byte#4  1001   1001
    Round#0 Byte#5  1011   0011
    Round#0 Byte#6  0110   1000

    Round#1  Byte#0  1000   0011
    Round#1  Byte#1  0001   0110
    Round#1  Byte#2  0010   1100
    Round#1  Byte#3  1001   1001
    Round#1  Byte#4  0011   0011
    Round#1  Byte#5  0110   0110
    Round#1  Byte#6  1101   0001

    Round#2  Byte#0  0000   0110
    Round#2  Byte#1  0010   1100
    Round#2  Byte#2  0101   1000 //error here => 0101 1001
    Round#2  Byte#3  0011   0000 //error here => 0011 0010
    Round#2  Byte#4  0110   0110
    Round#2  Byte#5  1100   1101
    Round#2  Byte#6  1010   0011
```

Comment: I think your best option is to find a working implementation of DES, and then step through both that version and your version in parallel, to identify where their behaviours differ.

Comment: I did try getting it, but couldn't find anything I could understand. Can u guide me as to where can I find it..?

Comment: A [Google search for "DES implementation"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22DES+implementation%22) reveals dozens of links.  I'm sure one of them is useful...

Comment: Well, they use crypto libraries and complex in-built functions. I am trying to do it from scratch. I can also work with any libraries or programs that will show me all the 16 keys for a given input, so that I can compare my logic. And there are online DES implementations that will encrypt and decrypt for you, but I can't use them (not yet :-) )
I am using this algorithm:
http://www.eventid.net/show.asp?DocId=19
The implementation is what's bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

The convention with DES is to pretend you have 64 bit keys (8 bytes), but if you want to be really, uhh, pedantic, you clobber the 8th bit of each of these bytes with the parity of preceding 7 bits.

I've only played with Java, and I've seen that Java (Sun/Oracle JRE) doesn't bother checking parity.  It just ignores the 8th bit of each byte.

Maybe the `DESEngine` in BouncyCastle will be of some help to you.  The `generateWorkingKey()` method looks interesting:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/viewcvs/viewcvs.cgi/java/crypto/src/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/DESEngine.java?view=markup

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Julius, but we need to implement DES from scratch, no in-built classes allowed..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you had it right in the first place (sort of):

```
// rightKey28[0] = (byte) (key56[3] & 00001111);
```

But you replaced it with subtraction:

```
rightKey28[0] = (byte) (key56[3] - leftKey28[3]);
```

If you want the first byte of `rightKey28` to have its four least-order bits set, your original code was (almost) correct; the new code is wrong.

The "sort of" and "almost" refer to the fact that binary literals are not supported until Java 7. So "11110000" is a decimal integer, with a binary pattern of `101010011000011001110000`. It almost works by coincidence, but you miss the highest order bit; I think what you want here is `0xF0` (and `0x0F` for the low order bits).

Also, these parts looks suspect:

```
circularBit = (byte) (rightKey28[0] & (1 << 3));
circularBit <<= 4;
```

This is moving the "circular" bit to the high order position in the byte: `X000000`.

But later you shift it right only 3 bits:

```
rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] << 1);
rightKey28[3] = (byte) (rightKey28[3] | ((((int) circularBit) & 0xff) >>> 3));
```

If `rightKey28[3]` starts with a bit pattern `ABCDEFGH`, it will end up with pattern `BCDYFGH0`, where `Y` is the logical result of `X | E`. Don't you really want `BCDEFGHX`? If so, you right shift `circularBit` by 7 bits.

Finally, note that `rightKey[0]` will have 5 bits set, because you shift the 4 bits it starts with left by 1. You may want to mask to ensure only the low order 4 bits contain data:

```
rightKey28[0] = (byte) ((rightKey28[0] << 1) & 0x0F);
```

Comment: Thanks!! I will try your suggestions, its early morning here in India..  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my DES code (incomplete in C).
Well, I tried Java for 2 weeks, and was having trouble with using long for ints, ints for bytes and shorts, etc (for bit manipulation/bit-shifting).
Then, gave up on Java and did this in C. It is the encryption code only.
Hope it helps someone in the future. Let me know if I am incorrect anywhere.
Thanks to all you guys for the help.

```
/*
 * des.c
 *  Created on: 2-Aug-2011
 *  Author: krish
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define KEY_LENGTH 8 // 8 char key, 64 bits
#define BLOCK_SIZE 8 // 8 char blocks, 64 bits
#define NUM_ROUNDS 16 // 16 uintRounds per block
// =======================================================================
// S-BOXES
int gSBox_1 = { { 14, 4, 13, 1, 2, 15, 11, 8, 3, 10, 6, 12, 5, 9, 0, 7 },
                { 0, 15, 7, 4, 14, 2, 13, 1, 10, 6, 12, 11, 9, 5, 3, 8 },
                { 4, 1, 14, 8, 13, 6, 2, 11, 15, 12, 9, 7, 3, 10, 5, 0 },
                { 15, 12, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 7, 5, 11, 3, 14, 10, 0, 6, 13 }
            }; //gSBox_1[8][8]

int getSBoxValue(int sbox,char position)
{
}
/*
 int sbox_2[] = { 15, 1, 8, 14, 6, 11, 3, 4, 9, 7, 2, 13, 12, 0, 5, 10, 3,
 13, 4, 7, 15, 2, 8, 14, 12, 0, 1, 10, 6, 9, 11, 5, 0, 14, 7, 11,
 10, 4, 13, 1, 5, 8, 12, 6, 9, 3, 2, 15, 13, 8, 10, 1, 3, 15, 4, 2,
 11, 6, 7, 12, 0, 5, 14, 9, };

 int sbox_3[] = { 10, 0, 9, 14, 6, 3, 15, 5, 1, 13, 12, 7, 11, 4, 2, 8, 13,
 7, 0, 9, 3, 4, 6, 10, 2, 8, 5, 14, 12, 11, 15, 1, 13, 6, 4, 9, 8,
 15, 3, 0, 11, 1, 2, 12, 5, 10, 14, 7, 1, 10, 13, 0, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4,
 15, 14, 3, 11, 5, 2, 12, };

 int sbox_4[] = { 7, 13, 14, 3, 0, 6, 9, 10, 1, 2, 8, 5, 11, 12, 4, 15, 13,
 8, 11, 5, 6, 15, 0, 3, 4, 7, 2, 12, 1, 10, 14, 9, 10, 6, 9, 0, 12,
 11, 7, 13, 15, 1, 3, 14, 5, 2, 8, 4, 3, 15, 0, 6, 10, 1, 13, 8, 9,
 4, 5, 11, 12, 7, 2, 14, };

 int sbox_5[] = { 2, 12, 4, 1, 7, 10, 11, 6, 8, 5, 3, 15, 13, 0, 14, 9, 14,
 11, 2, 12, 4, 7, 13, 1, 5, 0, 15, 10, 3, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 11, 10,
 13, 7, 8, 15, 9, 12, 5, 6, 3, 0, 14, 11, 8, 12, 7, 1, 14, 2, 13, 6,
 15, 0, 9, 10, 4, 5, 3, };

 int sbox_6[] = { 12, 1, 10, 15, 9, 2, 6, 8, 0, 13, 3, 4, 14, 7, 5, 11, 10,
 15, 4, 2, 7, 12, 9, 5, 6, 1, 13, 14, 0, 11, 3, 8, 9, 14, 15, 5, 2,
 8, 12, 3, 7, 0, 4, 10, 1, 13, 11, 6, 4, 3, 2, 12, 9, 5, 15, 10, 11,
 14, 1, 7, 6, 0, 8, 13, };

 int sbox_7[] = { 4, 11, 2, 14, 15, 0, 8, 13, 3, 12, 9, 7, 5, 10, 6, 1, 13,
 0, 11, 7, 4, 9, 1, 10, 14, 3, 5, 12, 2, 15, 8, 6, 1, 4, 11, 13, 12,
 3, 7, 14, 10, 15, 6, 8, 0, 5, 9, 2, 6, 11, 13, 8, 1, 4, 10, 7, 9,
 5, 0, 15, 14, 2, 3, 12, };

 int sbox_8[] = { 13, 2, 8, 4, 6, 15, 11, 1, 10, 9, 3, 14, 5, 0, 12, 7, 1,
 15, 13, 8, 10, 3, 7, 4, 12, 5, 6, 11, 0, 14, 9, 2, 7, 11, 4, 1, 9,
 12, 14, 2, 0, 6, 10, 13, 15, 3, 5, 8, 2, 1, 14, 7, 4, 10, 8, 13,
 15, 12, 9, 0, 3, 5, 6, 11 };

 // =======================================================================
 */

void getKey(char *key64) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    printf("\nEnter an 8 char key: ");
    returnValue = scanf("%[a-zA-Z0-9]s", key64);
    if (!returnValue) {
        printf("\nError in scanf enintCountered.. Exiting...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // key length() >= 8 chars
    printf("\nInput key: %s\n", key64);
    if (strlen(key64) != 8) {
        printf("Key <> 8 bytes. Exiting. . .");
        exit(3);
    }
}

void getMessage(char *inputMsg) {
    int returnValue = 0;
    printf("\nEnter a message: ");
    returnValue = scanf(" %[A-Za-z0-9. ]s", inputMsg);
    if (!returnValue) {
        printf("\nError in scanf enintCountered.. Exiting...\n");
        exit(2);
    }
}

void compressKey(char *key64, char *key56) {
    int intCounter;
    // conversion -64bit key to 56 bit key - starts here
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < KEY_LENGTH; intCounter++) {
        key64[intCounter] >>= 1;
        key64[intCounter] <<= 1;
    }
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < KEY_LENGTH - 1; intCounter++) {
        key56[intCounter] = key64[intCounter] << intCounter;
        key56[intCounter] = key56[intCounter] | ((key64[intCounter + 1]
                >> (KEY_LENGTH - 1 - intCounter)));
    }
    // conversion -64bit key to 56 bit key - ends here
}

char expandPlainText(unsigned uintCurrBits, unsigned uintPrevBit,
        unsigned uintNextBit) {
    char resultPtr;
    //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
    resultPtr = (char) (uintCurrBits & 0xff);
    resultPtr |= (uintPrevBit << 4);
    resultPtr <<= 1;
    resultPtr |= (uintNextBit);

    //printf("'%d'", resultPtr);
    return resultPtr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // =======================================================================
    // FOR KEY TRANSFORMATION
    int compressionPermutation[] = { 14, 17, 11, 24, 1, 5, 3, 28, 15, 6, 21,
            10, 23, 19, 12, 4, 26, 8, 16, 7, 27, 20, 13, 2, 41, 52, 31, 37, 47,
            55, 30, 40, 51, 45, 33, 48, 44, 49, 39, 56, 34, 53, 46, 42, 50, 36,
            29, 32 };

    //int keyShiftValue[16] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 };---don't need this
    // =======================================================================

    // =======================================================================
    // FOR PLAINTEXT TRANSFORMATION
    int
            initialPermutation[] = { 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 60, 52, 44,
                    36, 28, 20, 12, 4, 62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 64, 56,
                    48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17, 9, 1, 59,
                    51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3, 61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5,
                    63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7 };

    /*int
     finalPermutation[] = { 40, 8, 48, 16, 56, 24, 64, 32, 39, 7, 47,
     15, 55, 23, 63, 31, 38, 6, 46, 14, 54, 22, 62, 30, 37, 5,
     45, 13, 53, 21, 61, 29, 36, 4, 44, 12, 52, 20, 60, 28, 35,
     3, 43, 11, 51, 19, 59, 27, 34, 2, 42, 10, 50, 18, 58, 26,
     33, 1, 41, 9, 49, 17, 57, 25 };

     int permutationFunction[] = { 16, 7, 20, 21, 29, 12, 28, 17, 1, 15, 23, 26,
     5, 18, 31, 10, 2, 8, 24, 14, 32, 27, 3, 9, 19, 13, 30, 6, 22, 11,
     4, 25 };

     int expansionPermutation[] = { 32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9,
     10, 11, 12, 13, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 20,
     21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 1 };
     // ---
     // don't need this
     */
    // =======================================================================


    char *key64 = (char *) calloc(9, sizeof(char)); //stores user input key
    char *key56 = (char *) calloc(8, sizeof(char)); //56 bit key

    char newKey56[16][7]; //used for key transformation
    char compressedKey[16][6]; //stores compressed keys
    char leftKey28[4], rightKey28[4];
    unsigned int uintLeftTemp, uintRightTemp, uintCircularBit;

    char *inputMsg = (char *) calloc(BLOCK_SIZE * 10, sizeof(char));
    char *permutedPlaintextBlock =
            (char *) calloc(BLOCK_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char)); //to store permuted plaintetx
    char *plaintextBlock = (char *) calloc(BLOCK_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char)); // to store 1 block of plaintext
    char expandedRightPlaintext[8];
    //char expandedLeftPlaintext[8];// = (char *) calloc(BLOCK_SIZE + 1, sizeof(char));
    char expandedPlaintext[6], XORedText[6], sboxText[8], encryptedText[4];

    unsigned int uintCurrBits, uintPrevBit, uintNextBit;

    int intCounter, intCounter1, intCounter2; //keep this signed!!!$$$$$$$$$$$$$
    unsigned int uintNumBlocks, uintTempInteger, uintRound, uintPaddingSpaces;

    getKey(key64);
    getMessage(inputMsg);

    //printing test code starts here
    printf("\nInput key in binary:\n");
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 8; intCounter++) {
        for (intCounter1 = 7; intCounter1 >= 0; intCounter1--) {
            if ((key64[intCounter] & (1 << intCounter1)) > 0)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    //printing test code ends here

    compressKey(key64, key56);

    //printing test code starts here
    printf("\n64 to 56 bit key:\n");
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 7; intCounter++) {
        for (intCounter1 = 7; intCounter1 >= 0; intCounter1--) {
            if ((key56[intCounter] & (1 << intCounter1)) > 0)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    //printing test code ends here

    ////////////////////////////////
    // KEY TRANSFORMATION PHASE
    ////////////////////////////////


    // new 56 bit key for the first uintRound, then loop for other uintRounds


    leftKey28[0] = key56[0];
    leftKey28[1] = key56[1];
    leftKey28[2] = key56[2];
    leftKey28[3] = key56[3] & 0xf0;

    rightKey28[0] = key56[3] & 0x0f;
    rightKey28[1] = key56[4];
    rightKey28[2] = key56[5];
    rightKey28[3] = key56[6];

    uintLeftTemp = 0;
    uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[0]) & 0xff) << 24);
    uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[1]) & 0xff) << 16);
    uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[2]) & 0xff) << 8);
    uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[3]) & 0xff) << 0);

    uintRightTemp = 0;
    uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[0]) & 0xff) << 24);
    uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[1]) & 0xff) << 16);
    uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[2]) & 0xff) << 8);
    uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[3]) & 0xff) << 0);

    uintCircularBit = uintLeftTemp & (1 << 31);
    uintCircularBit = uintCircularBit >> 31;

    uintLeftTemp <<= 1;
    uintLeftTemp |= (uintCircularBit << 4);

    uintCircularBit = uintRightTemp & (1 << 27);
    uintCircularBit >>= 27;

    uintRightTemp <<= 1;
    uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp & 0x0fffffff;
    uintRightTemp |= (uintCircularBit);

    //convert uintLeftTemp to leftKey28 again
    leftKey28[0] = uintLeftTemp >> 24;
    leftKey28[1] = uintLeftTemp >> 16;
    leftKey28[2] = uintLeftTemp >> 8;
    leftKey28[3] = uintLeftTemp >> 0;

    rightKey28[0] = uintRightTemp >> 24;
    rightKey28[1] = uintRightTemp >> 16;
    rightKey28[2] = uintRightTemp >> 8;
    rightKey28[3] = uintRightTemp >> 0;

    newKey56[0][0] = leftKey28[0];
    newKey56[0][1] = leftKey28[1];
    newKey56[0][2] = leftKey28[2];
    newKey56[0][3] = leftKey28[3] | rightKey28[0];
    newKey56[0][4] = rightKey28[1];
    newKey56[0][5] = rightKey28[2];
    newKey56[0][6] = rightKey28[3];

    // have a new left circular shifted key in newKey56[0]
    //*******************

    //printing test code starts here
    printf("\nnewKey56[0] key: ");
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 7; intCounter++) {
        for (intCounter1 = 7; intCounter1 >= 0; intCounter1--) {
            if ((newKey56[0][intCounter] & (1 << intCounter1)) > 0)
                printf("1");
            else
                printf("0");
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    //printing test code ends here

    // for uintRound 1 to 15: left circular shift each 28 bit block by 1{
    for (uintRound = 1; uintRound < NUM_ROUNDS; uintRound++) {
        leftKey28[0] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][0];
        leftKey28[1] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][1];
        leftKey28[2] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][2];
        leftKey28[3] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][3] & 0xf0;
        rightKey28[0] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][3] & 0x0f;
        rightKey28[1] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][4];
        rightKey28[2] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][5];
        rightKey28[3] = newKey56[uintRound - 1][6];

        uintLeftTemp = 0;
        uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[0]) & 0xff) << 24);
        uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[1]) & 0xff) << 16);
        uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[2]) & 0xff) << 8);
        uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp | ((((int) leftKey28[3]) & 0xff) << 0);

        uintRightTemp = 0;
        uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[0]) & 0xff) << 24);
        uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[1]) & 0xff) << 16);
        uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[2]) & 0xff) << 8);
        uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp | ((((int) rightKey28[3]) & 0xff) << 0);

        if (uintRound == 1 || uintRound == 8 || uintRound == 15) {
            //left circular shift by 1
            uintCircularBit = uintLeftTemp & (1 << 31);
            uintCircularBit = uintCircularBit >> 31;

            uintLeftTemp <<= 1;
            uintLeftTemp |= (uintCircularBit << 4);

            uintCircularBit = uintRightTemp & (1 << 27);
            uintCircularBit >>= 27;

            uintRightTemp <<= 1;
            uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp & 0x0fffffff;
            uintRightTemp |= (uintCircularBit);
        } else {
            //left circular shift by 2
            uintCircularBit = 0;
            uintCircularBit = uintLeftTemp & (11 << 30);

            uintCircularBit = uintCircularBit >> 30;

            uintLeftTemp <<= 2;
            uintLeftTemp |= uintCircularBit << 4;

            uintCircularBit = 0;
            uintCircularBit = uintRightTemp & (11 << 26);
            uintCircularBit >>= 26;

            uintRightTemp <<= 2;
            uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp & 0x0fffffff;
            uintRightTemp |= (uintCircularBit);
        }

        //convert uintLeftTemp to leftKey28 again
        leftKey28[0] = uintLeftTemp >> 24;
        leftKey28[1] = uintLeftTemp >> 16;
        leftKey28[2] = uintLeftTemp >> 8;
        leftKey28[3] = uintLeftTemp >> 0;

        rightKey28[0] = uintRightTemp >> 24;
        rightKey28[1] = uintRightTemp >> 16;
        rightKey28[2] = uintRightTemp >> 8;
        rightKey28[3] = uintRightTemp >> 0;

        newKey56[uintRound][0] = leftKey28[0];
        newKey56[uintRound][1] = leftKey28[1];
        newKey56[uintRound][2] = leftKey28[2];
        newKey56[uintRound][3] = leftKey28[3] | rightKey28[0];
        newKey56[uintRound][4] = rightKey28[1];
        newKey56[uintRound][5] = rightKey28[2];
        newKey56[uintRound][6] = rightKey28[3];

        //printing test code starts here
        printf("\nnewKey56[%d]: ", uintRound);
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 7; intCounter++) {
            for (intCounter1 = 7; intCounter1 >= 0; intCounter1--) {
                if ((newKey56[uintRound][intCounter] & (1 << intCounter1)) > 0)
                    printf("1");
                else
                    printf("0");
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
        //printing test code ends here
    }// for loop ends

    ////////////////////////////////
    // KEY COMPRESSION PHASE
    ////////////////////////////////

    for (uintRound = 0; uintRound < NUM_ROUNDS; uintRound++) {
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 48; intCounter++) {
            uintTempInteger = 0;
            uintTempInteger
                    = ((int) (newKey56[uintRound][(compressionPermutation[intCounter]
                            - 1) / 8])) & (1 << (7
                            - ((compressionPermutation[intCounter] - 1) % 8)));

            // test code for printing temp value - starts here
            if (uintTempInteger > 0) {
                compressedKey[uintRound][intCounter / 8] |= (1 << (7
                        - (intCounter % 8)));
            }
        }
    }

    //printing test code starts here
    for (intCounter1 = 0; intCounter1 < NUM_ROUNDS; intCounter1++) {
        printf("\ncompressedKey[%d]:  ", intCounter1);
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < 6; intCounter++) {
            for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                if ((compressedKey[intCounter1][intCounter]
                        & (1 << intCounter2)) > 0)
                    printf("1");
                else
                    printf("0");
            }
            printf(" ");
        }
    }
    //printing test code ends here*/
    // KEY COMPRESSION DONE

    //////////////////////////
    // WORKING WITH PLAINTEXT
    //////////////////////////

    printf("\n'%s'\n", inputMsg);
    // if input length not a multiple of BLOCK_SIZE, pad it with spaces(ascii:32)
    if (strlen(inputMsg) % BLOCK_SIZE != 0) {
        uintPaddingSpaces = BLOCK_SIZE - (strlen(inputMsg) % BLOCK_SIZE);
        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < uintPaddingSpaces; intCounter++)
            strcat(inputMsg, " ");
    }
    uintNumBlocks = strlen(inputMsg) / 8;
    printf("\n'%s'\n'%d'\n", inputMsg, uintNumBlocks);

    //intCounter1, intCounter2, uintRound;
    for (intCounter = 0; intCounter < uintNumBlocks; intCounter++) {

        for (intCounter1 = 0; intCounter1 < BLOCK_SIZE; intCounter1++) {
            plaintextBlock[intCounter1] = inputMsg[intCounter * BLOCK_SIZE
                    + intCounter1];
        }
        printf("'%s'", plaintextBlock);

        ////////////////////////////////
        // INITIAL PERMUTATION FOR EACH BLOCK
        ////////////////////////////////

        for (uintRound = 0; uintRound < NUM_ROUNDS; uintRound++) {
            for (intCounter1 = 0; intCounter1 < 64; intCounter1++) {
                uintTempInteger = 0;
                uintTempInteger
                        = (((int) (plaintextBlock[(initialPermutation[intCounter1]
                                - 1) / 8])) & 0xff) & (1 << (7
                                - ((initialPermutation[intCounter1] - 1) % 8)));

                // test code for printing temp value - starts here
                if (uintTempInteger > 0) {
                    permutedPlaintextBlock[intCounter1 / 8] |= (1 << (7
                            - (intCounter1 % 8)));
                }
            }
            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nBlock # %d uintRound # %d: ", intCounter, uintRound);
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < BLOCK_SIZE; uintTempInteger++) {
                for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                    if ((permutedPlaintextBlock[uintTempInteger] & (1
                            << intCounter2)) > 0)
                        printf("1");
                    else
                        printf("0");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            /* IP DONE
             * After IP, divide into leftPT and rightPT - 32 bits each
             * do expansion permutation
             * then do the 16 rounds
             */

            uintLeftTemp = 0;

            uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp
                    | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[0]) & 0xff)
                            << 24);
            uintLeftTemp = uintLeftTemp
                    | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[1]) & 0xff)
                            << 16);
            uintLeftTemp
                    = uintLeftTemp
                            | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[2])
                                    & 0xff) << 8);
            uintLeftTemp
                    = uintLeftTemp
                            | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[3])
                                    & 0xff) << 0);

            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nuintLeftTemp: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 32; uintTempInteger > 0; uintTempInteger--) {

                if ((uintTempInteger) % 8 == 0)
                    printf(" ");
                if ((uintLeftTemp & (1 << (uintTempInteger - 1))) > 0)
                    printf("1");
                else
                    printf("0");

            }
            //printing test code ends here


            uintRightTemp = 0;
            uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp
                    | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[4]) & 0xff)
                            << 24);
            uintRightTemp = uintRightTemp
                    | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[5]) & 0xff)
                            << 16);
            uintRightTemp
                    = uintRightTemp
                            | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[6])
                                    & 0xff) << 8);
            uintRightTemp
                    = uintRightTemp
                            | ((((unsigned int) permutedPlaintextBlock[7])
                                    & 0xff) << 0);

            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nuintRightTemp: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 32; uintTempInteger > 0; uintTempInteger--) {
                if ((uintTempInteger) % 8 == 0)
                    printf(" ");
                if ((uintRightTemp & (1 << (uintTempInteger - 1))) > 0)
                    printf("1");
                else
                    printf("0");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            //done getting LPT & RPT
            /*
             * 32 bit RPT divided into 8 blks of 4 bits each
             * 4 bit block converted into 6 bit block by adding prev blks'
             * last bit and next blks' first bit
             */

            //for block 0
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 28) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 27) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 0) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[0] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[0]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[0]);

            //for block 1
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 24) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 23) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 28) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[1] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[1]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[1]);

            //for block 2
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 20) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 19) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 24) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[2] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[2]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[2]);

            //for block 3
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 16) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 15) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 20) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[3] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[3]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[3]);

            //for block 4
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 12) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 11) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 16) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[4] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[4]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[4]);

            //for block 5
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 8) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 7) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 12) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[5] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[5]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[5]);

            //for block 6
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 4) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 3) & 0x01;
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 8) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[6] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[6]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[6]);

            //for block 7
            uintCurrBits = (uintRightTemp >> 0) & 0x0f;
            uintNextBit = (uintRightTemp >> 31) & 0x01;//********
            uintPrevBit = (uintRightTemp >> 4) & 0x01;
            //printf("\n%d %d %d\n", uintCurrBits, uintNextBit, uintPrevBit);
            expandedRightPlaintext[7] = expandPlainText(uintCurrBits,
                    uintPrevBit, uintNextBit);
            //printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext[7]: '%d'",expandedRightPlaintext[7]);

            //combine expandedRightPlaintext[0..7] to get a 48 bit RPT
            //XOR with 48bit compressedKey and give result to SBox
            //char compressedKey[16][6]; //stores compressed keys

            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nexpandedRightPlaintext: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < BLOCK_SIZE; uintTempInteger++) {
                for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                    if ((expandedRightPlaintext[uintTempInteger] & (1
                            << intCounter2)) > 0)
                        printf("1");
                    else
                        printf("0");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            // conversion - 64 bit key to 48 bit RPT - starts here
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < BLOCK_SIZE; uintTempInteger++)
                expandedRightPlaintext[uintTempInteger] <<= 2;

            expandedPlaintext[0] = (expandedRightPlaintext[0] << 0)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[1] >> 6);

            expandedPlaintext[1] = (expandedRightPlaintext[1] << 2)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[2] >> 4);

            expandedPlaintext[2] = (expandedRightPlaintext[2] << 4)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[3] >> 2);

            expandedPlaintext[3] = (expandedRightPlaintext[4] << 0)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[5] >> 6);

            expandedPlaintext[4] = (expandedRightPlaintext[5] << 2)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[6] >> 4);

            expandedPlaintext[5] = (expandedRightPlaintext[6] << 4)
                    | (expandedRightPlaintext[7] >> 2);

            // conversion - 64 bit key to 48 bit RPT - ends here
            //we have a 48 bit plaintext in expandedPlaintext and a 48 bit key in compressedKey

            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nexpandedPlaintext: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < 6; uintTempInteger++) {
                for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                    if ((expandedPlaintext[uintTempInteger]
                            & (1 << intCounter2)) > 0)
                        printf("1");
                    else
                        printf("0");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            /* 48 bit RPT XORed with 48 bit key, then Sbox sub
             * XORing here
             */
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < 6; uintTempInteger++)
                XORedText[uintTempInteger] = expandedPlaintext[uintTempInteger]
                        ^ compressedKey[uintRound][uintTempInteger];
            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nXORedPlaintext: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < 6; uintTempInteger++) {
                for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                    if ((XORedText[uintTempInteger] & (1 << intCounter2)) > 0)
                        printf("1");
                    else
                        printf("0");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            // converting XORed text to blocks of 6 bits
            //XORedPlaintext: 110111 01 10101101 00001000  01011011 10111011 01000010
            sboxText[0] = (XORedText[0] >> 2) & 0x3f;
            sboxText[1] = ((XORedText[0] & 0x03) << 4) | ((XORedText[1] >> 4)
                    & 0x0f);
            sboxText[2] = ((XORedText[1] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((XORedText[2] >> 6)
                    & 0x03);
            sboxText[3] = XORedText[2] & 0x3f;
            sboxText[4] = (XORedText[3] >> 2) & 0x3f;
            sboxText[5] = ((XORedText[3] & 0x03) << 4) | ((XORedText[4] >> 4)
                    & 0x0f);
            sboxText[6] = ((XORedText[4] & 0x0f) << 2) | ((XORedText[5] >> 6)
                    & 0x03);
            sboxText[7] = XORedText[5] & 0x3f;

            //printing test code starts here
            printf("\nsboxText: ");
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < BLOCK_SIZE; uintTempInteger++) {
                for (intCounter2 = 7; intCounter2 >= 0; intCounter2--) {
                    if ((sboxText[uintTempInteger] & (1 << intCounter2)) > 0)
                        printf("1");
                    else
                        printf("0");
                }
                printf(" ");
            }
            //printing test code ends here

            //CORRECT TILL HERE
            for (uintTempInteger = 0; uintTempInteger < 4; uintTempInteger++) {
                encryptedText[uintTempInteger]=getSBoxValue(gSBox_1,sboxText[uintTempInteger]);
                encryptedText[0]<<=4;
                encryptedText[uintTempInteger]=getSBoxValue(gSBox_1,sboxText[uintTempInteger+1]);
            }
            printf("\nencrypt: %d",encryptedText[0]);

            break;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nSAFE EXIT\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
 *
 * TEST ROUTINES HERE
 *
 * //printing test code starts here
 printf("\nleftKey28:\n");
 for(intCounter=0;intCounter<4;intCounter++)
 {
 for(intCounter1=7;intCounter1>=0;intCounter1--)
 {
 if((leftKey28[intCounter] & (1 << intCounter1)) > 0)
 printf("1");
 else
 printf("0");
 }
 printf(" ");
 }
 printf("\n");
 //printing test code ends here*/

//printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", sizeof(int),sizeof(long int),sizeof(char));
//sizeof char = 8 bits
//sizeof int = 32 bits
//sizeof long = 64 bits

///
///
```